# Are there any alternatives for "-webkit-box-orient"

Tags: css, text, browser, cross-browser

Are there any alternatives for `-webkit-box-orient`?

I need it for the following class:

```
.max-2-lines{
    overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

However i can see [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-box-orient) that only few browsers support that property

Comment: @Paulie_D can you please explain a little bit more what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are using the *old* implementation of `line-clamp` that require the use of `-webkit-box` and `-webkit-box-orient`.

In the near future you will only need to use the `line-clamp` property:

> The `line-clamp` property is a shorthand for the `max-lines`, `block-ellipsis`, and `continue` properties.
>
> It allows limiting the contents of a block container to the specified number of lines; remaining content is fragmented away and neither rendered nor measured. Optionally, it also allows inserting content into the last line box to indicate the continuity of truncated/interrupted content. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#propdef-block-ellipsis)</sup>

You can also check the [Legacy compatibility](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#propdef-block-ellipsis) section for more information

Comment: so in order to have just (example) 2 lines, i should only one `line-clamp: 2`? can you please also provide a small example?

Comment: @Berto99 unfortunately the support is still low, I don't think any browser is implementing this. The specification is also in Draft mode. Actually the only way you have is the code you are using.

Comment: now it explains why  i can't get it to work ahah thank you

Comment: i'll wait for other answer in the near future, and if no more answer will be posted, i'll mark this as correct, thank you again

Comment: @Berto99 yes sure, no hurry for the accept, someone will probably come with more information and another technique